# How do I disable lan Isolation in ISP provided router (ZTE ZXHN F680)

Tags: networking, router, lan

My ISP (Maroc Telecom, from Morocco) provided me with a ZTE ZXHN F680 router and I want to disable Lan isolation since I can't access other Lan devices on my network (Wifi access points). And I have been looking through the setting and google for how disable it and it has been 2 weeks and still couldn't figure it out.

[This is the only manual that I could find for the router](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2235582/Zte-Zxhn-F680.html)

Does anyone have a solution for it,

Thanks for the help

Comment: There is not normally a setting for LAN isolation. Sometimes a router may have Wireless Isolation but I searched the manual and did not find that. Have you set this router up on a different subnet than your other gear?  That will cause what you see.

Comment: Buy your own router

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @John For some reason wireless isolation is disabled by default.If i'm connected via Wifi, I can ping any device on the network, but when wired to my laptop I cannot. I haven't changed any setting regarding subnets on my other devices. I will do more digging but I that doesn't work out, I might just buy my own router

Comment: So the issue is wireless isolation.  If not your router and no setting for it (none I could see in the approximate manual), then having your own router is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

I have the ZTE F660 from the same ISP and in my experience LAN port 4 seems to be isolated for me but not the first 3. Maybe that's your issue, try the other ports.

This behavior is with Lan Isolation disabled. Maybe the last port is supposed to be for WAN and that's why it's behaving differently even in a normal LAN setting.